# StyleCop shows warnings for old rules on build

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, stylecop

I'm Sören and this is my first question on stackoverflow :)

Since I started a new project (where I use StyleCop) I decided to try the newer StyleCop solution via Nuget-Packages (Analyzers and MsBuild).
So I set it up, got my rulessets working and code analysis works fine for me.

There is just one problem I can't solve. As mentioned I installed the StyleCop.MsBuild package to allow build on TFS. So when I rebuild my project, StyleCop runs and gives some warnings. BUT... It shows warnings for rules that doesn't exist anymore (SA1126). So it uses other settings than my ruleset. Has anyone experienced similar problems or any idea to solve this?

best regards,
Sören

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StyleCop.MSBuild brings its own StyleCop binaries etc. and uses StyleCop.settings. I want to use StyleCop.Analyzers with rulesets, so I can run it via code analysis and don't have to install StyleCop.

So without StyleCop.MSBuild the problem doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone experienced similar problems or any idea to solve this?

Do you want to disable the stylecop warnings SA1126? If yes, you can trick StyleCop into not processing a file at all by adding this header at the top of .cs file:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
// Well, not really. This is just a trick to get StyleCop off my back.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```